# QuickSort program not working

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am simply trying to implement Quicksort on strings but it isn't working. The output comes out to be the same as the input and not the sorted string. I have checked many times but am not able to find any error. Please help me out.

Below is the quicksort function.

```
void quicksort(string str1, int si, int ei)
{
    if (si < ei)
    {
        int pi = partition(str1, si, ei);
        quicksort(str1, si, pi-1);
        quicksort(str1, pi+1, ei);
    }
}
```

The Partition function.

```
int partition(string str2, int si, int ei)
{
    int i = si-1;
    char x = str2[ei];
    int j;
    for (j = si ; j <= ei-1 ; j++)
    {
        if (str2[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            exchange(&str2[i], &str2[j]);
        }
    }
    exchange(&str2[ei], &str2[i+1]);
    return i+1;
}
```

and the exchange function.

```
void exchange(char *a, char *b)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

The main function is as given below.

```
int main()
{
    int l1;
    string str;
    cout << "Enter the string to be sorted";
    cin >> str;
    l1 = str.length();
    quicksort(str, 0, l1-1);
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The backtick is for inline code formatting. Use 4 spaces at the beginning of each line for blocks of code (plus additional spaces for further indenting).

Comment: What tests have you written for these functions?

Comment: I am asking the user to enter the string and haven't hard coded the test cases. I have tried entering strings like "dbca", "adbc" and even numbers such as "1243" @AlanStokes

Comment: Thanks @crashmstr I'll remember that the next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`quicksort` takes `str1` by value, and then recursively copies it to its subproblems. Each instantiation is operating on a separate, unrelated string and making modifications to its local copy.

You need to pass `str` by reference:

```
void quicksort(string& str1, int si, int ei)
```

And same for `partition`:

```
int partition(string& str2, int si, int ei)
```

Comment: It worked. For the past two days I was tired of analysing my code and I never noticed this thing. Thank you so much @Barry